# Android cloud Firestore Get Multiple Collections From Multiple Locations

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I can't set  data.setFavourite(isfavorite) because that data comes late. What should I do to properly fill the list.if i scrol list then it set direct not set.

I started a new project. And I'm trying to use Firebase. I try to unite the two collections and then try to combine them.

My database structure:

```
Bhajan
    [Bhajanid]
        Bhajantitle:"Bhajantitle"       
Favourite
    [id]
        bhajanid=bhajanid [from Bhajan Collection]
```

if avilable then set bhajan id set true

```
 myfirebase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    myfirebase.collection(confing.GUJARATIBHAJAN_COLLECTION)
            .whereEqualTo(confing.BhajanStatus, "Active")
            .addSnapshotListener(ExampleTagActivity.this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable final QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    if (e != null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    index_dataArrayList.clear();
                    filterlist.clear();
                    final boolean[] isfavorite = {false};
                    for (final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        final index_data data = new index_data();
                        data.setId((documentSnapshot.getId()));
                        data.setUserdocid((documentSnapshot.getId()));
                        data.setNo(documentSnapshot.getString(confing.SrNo));
                        data.setTitle(documentSnapshot.getString(confing.BhajanTittle));
                        data.setDesc(documentSnapshot.getString(confing.BhajanDesc));
                        data.setBhajancar(documentSnapshot.getString(confing.BhajanKar));
                        data.setBhajanstatus(documentSnapshot.getString(confing.BhajanStatus));
                        data.setBhajanAudioPath(documentSnapshot.getString(confing.BhajanAudioPath));
                        String TagValue = String.valueOf(documentSnapshot.get(confing.BhajanTagName));
                        String TagValue1 = TagValue.replace("[", "");
                        final String TagValue2 = TagValue1.replace("]", "");
                        // data.set(String.valueOf(TagValue2));
                        data.setTags(new ArrayList<tag_row>() {{
                            add(new tag_row(TagValue2, getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)));
                        }});

                        final Query query = myfirebase.collection(confing.Favourite_COLLECTION)
                                .whereEqualTo(confing.Fav_BhajanId, data.getId())
                                .whereEqualTo(confing.Fav_UserImei, UserImei);
                        query.get()
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                        boolean isfavorite;
                                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            isfavorite = false;
                                            data.setFavourite(isfavorite);
                                        } else {
                                            for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot1 : task.getResult()) {
                                                if (documentSnapshot1.exists()) {
                                                    isfavorite = true;
                                                } else {
                                                    isfavorite = false;
                                                }
                                                data.setFavourite(isfavorite);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                        index_dataArrayList.add(data);
                        filterlist.add(data);
                    }
                    firecallback.Oncallback(filterlist);
                    firecallback.Oncallback(index_dataArrayList);

                }
            });
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you shared?

Comment: one listner method inside another another listner method second listner method break and not set data to

Comment: data.setFavourite(isfavorite); not set

Comment: if i scrol list then it set direct not set.